# How to add kafka-connect-spooldir plugin to Apache Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have downloaded kafka-connect-spooldir zip file and extracted it. Then I provided its lib folder's path in the connect-distributed.properties file like,

```
plugin.path=C:/Kafka/JDBC/kafka-connect-jdbc-10.4.0.jar,C:/kafka/jcustenborder-kafka-connect-spooldir-2.0.65/lib
```

Then after starting the kafka connect I got this error and it stops.

```
INFO Loading plugin from: C:\kafka\jcustenborder-kafka-connect-spooldir-2.0.65\lib\kafka-connect-spooldir-2.0.65.jar (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:275)
[2023-05-26 10:15:06,936] ERROR Stopping due to error (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed:89)
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/collect/Multimap
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:3473)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3678)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2854)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.versionFor(DelegatingClassLoader.java:439)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.getPluginDesc(DelegatingClassLoader.java:403)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.scanPluginPath(DelegatingClassLoader.java:365)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.scanUrlsAndAddPlugins(DelegatingClassLoader.java:296)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.registerPlugin(DelegatingClassLoader.java:289)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.initPluginLoader(DelegatingClassLoader.java:258)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.initLoaders(DelegatingClassLoader.java:236)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.Plugins.<init>(Plugins.java:65)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.Plugins.<init>(Plugins.java:58)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed.startConnect(ConnectDistributed.java:96)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed.main(ConnectDistributed.java:83)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.collect.Multimap
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:445)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:136)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        ... 15 more
```

This was solved by adding guava to kafka's lib folder and I got this error

```
INFO Loading plugin from: C:\kafka\jcustenborder-kafka-connect-spooldir-2.0.65\lib\kafka-connect-spooldir-2.0.65.jar (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:275)
[2023-05-26 10:40:38,293] ERROR Stopping due to error (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed:89)
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/github/jcustenborder/kafka/connect/utils/VersionUtil
        at com.github.jcustenborder.kafka.connect.spooldir.AbstractSpoolDirSourceConnector.version(AbstractSpoolDirSourceConnector.java:46)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.versionFor(DelegatingClassLoader.java:433)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.versionFor(DelegatingClassLoader.java:439)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.getPluginDesc(DelegatingClassLoader.java:403)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.scanPluginPath(DelegatingClassLoader.java:365)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.scanUrlsAndAddPlugins(DelegatingClassLoader.java:296)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.registerPlugin(DelegatingClassLoader.java:289)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.initPluginLoader(DelegatingClassLoader.java:258)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.initLoaders(DelegatingClassLoader.java:236)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.Plugins.<init>(Plugins.java:65)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.Plugins.<init>(Plugins.java:58)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed.startConnect(ConnectDistributed.java:96)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed.main(ConnectDistributed.java:83)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.github.jcustenborder.kafka.connect.utils.VersionUtil
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:445)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:136)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        ... 13 more
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check out this repo, `mvn clean package` it, then copy its JARs into the plugin path as well

https://github.com/jcustenborder/connect-utils

Comment: It didn't work when I provided the libs folder location from the downloaded kafka-connect-spooldir as plugin.path in connect-distributed.properties  file at first. When I added the jar files in the libs folder to apache kafka's lib folder, it worked.

Comment: You shouldn't modify the broker's classpath to fix Kafka Connect issues. Instead, you can export CLASSPATH env-var before running connect process.